# Halachic Hair Cut

Tags: halacha, hair, shaving, conservative-judaism, haircuts

I have a question in regards with cutting hair specifically in Conservative Judaism. Where cannot be shaved by a razor and where do sideburns have to reach up to. If someone could just give me the rundown on this, that'd be great.

Comment: http://oldschedu.com/AskTheRabbi.aspx?ID=204 perhaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience, the general stance on Lev. 19:27 ("you shall not round the corners of your heads") in Conservative communities is that it's not observed, and left to the individual to decide what he thinks of the mitzvah and how he wants to observe it. However, all Conservative Jews I've ever met haven't had peyot; it's just not a thing focused on in today's Conservative Judaism, especially nowadays. Of course, if you're interested in keeping this mitzvah, I'd suggest taking a look at this poster:

[image]

Good luck, and I hope this helps.